# Creating a mock object with default properties

Tags: php, phpunit

I need to create a mock object with default set of properties so it can be used elseware in the codebase upon instantiation.

```
$mock = $this->getMock('MyClass', array(), array(), 'MyClass_Mock');
$mock->prop = 'foobar';

$myclassMock = new get_class($mock);
var_dump($myclassMock->prop); // NULL
// How can I make this dump 'foobar' ?
```

I'm testing part of the framework that determines, locates, and instantiates these classes so injecting the mocked object would defeat the purpose of the test.

I don't need to mock any methods.. just dynamically create a mocked class like so:

```
class MyClass_Mock extends MyClass {
  public $prop = 'foobar';
}
```

Edit: Simplified example

Comment: Just for clarity, you want to mock an existing class, and give your mock the default properties of that class, without actually instantiating the class being mocked?

Comment: @Leigh Right, the class will be instantiated deeper in the framework. The class I'm mocking is an abstract model, and I want to give it some `$fields` so it will behave like a real model. I know PHPUnit creates mocks by writing the code into a string and evaling() it. I just don't know how to include property declarations in that process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you feel about using Reflection?

```
$r = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');

$props = $r->getDefaultProperties();

$mock = new stdClass;

foreach ($props as $prop => $value) {
    $mock->$prop = $value;
}
```

I've not used Reflection a whole lot myself, only for basic introspection. I'm not sure if you'll be able to fully mimic visibility etc. using it, but I don't see why not if you continue down the route of writing to a string and `eval`ing.

**Edit:**

Scanned through the Reflection functions out of curiosity, it is totally possible to fully mimic the class with dummy methods, implementing full visibility constraints, constants, and static elements where appropriate if you dynamically build the class in a string and `eval` it.

However it looks like it will be a complete ***mission*** to really fully support every possibility when it comes down to getting data types correct (you'll need code to rebuild an array constructor from an array for example)

Best of luck if you go down this route, it requires more brain power than I'm willing to spare right now :)

Here's a little bit of code, you can do the same thing with constants, and create empty methods in a similar way.

```
class Test
{
    private static $privates = 'priv';
    protected $protected = 'prot';
    public $public = 'pub';
}

$r = new ReflectionClass('Test');

$props = $r->getDefaultProperties();

$mock = 'class MockTest {';

foreach ($props as $prop => $value) {
    $rProp = $r->getProperty($prop);


    if ($rProp->isPrivate()) {
        $mock .= 'private ';
    }
    elseif ($rProp->isProtected()) {
        $mock .= 'protected ';
    }
    elseif ($rProp->isPublic()) {
        $mock .= 'public ';
    }

    if ($rProp->isStatic()) {
        $mock .= 'static ';
    }

    $mock .= "$$prop = ";

    switch (gettype($value)) {
        case "boolean":
        case "integer":
        case "double":
            $mock .= $value;
            break;
        case "string":
            $mock .= "'$value'";
            break;
/*
"array"
"object"
"resource"
*/
    case "NULL":
            $mock .= 'null';
            break;
    }

    $mock .= ';';
}

$mock .= '}';

eval($mock);

var_dump(new MockTest);
```

Comment: I'd upvote you twice if I could. Thanks for putting in the effort.. I haven't tried the reflection route thus far but it sounds interesting. I'll give some of your suggestions a try and see how it goes :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you even ***need*** to do this for testing purposes.

Usually when testing code that involves model access you use fixtures instead of mocking the actual models because models are "dumb" data structures that don't expose any capabilities that need to be mocked.

Your example bears this out: *if you don't need to mock behavior (methods), you don't need a mock object*. You need a data fixture instead that the model uses as its data source. This is especially true if, as you say, *"dependency injection isn't an option"*.

Of course, if you decide you want to mock the model anyway, I'd suggest @Leigh's reflection solution.

I just answered a question about database testing yesterday that you might check out for a bit more detail:
[PHPUnit: How to test database interactions on remote Postgres server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319885/phpunit-how-to-test-database-interactions-on-remote-postgres-server/9320378#9320378)

Comment: Good points. I guess you could say I'm trying to create a dynamic fixture. I'm trying to test the underlying model framework by creating faux models. Our models are configured almost entirely through protected properties so I can create a user model simply by having `protected $_fields = array('firstname, 'lastname');`. My goal is to have the ability to recreate any situation by building a fake model dynamically to test the underlying framework against. I've already mocked the data-gateways and the rest of the framework.. I just need the ability to create dynamic classes with default props

Comment: Aha I see. In that case, by all means, mock those models. Generally with something like that I'd base the model on a "collection" object that stored all the properties in a single protected array and implement `ArrayAccess` with magic `__get` and `__set` to make property read/write simple. If you did that you could throw in your own `Model::load` method to populate a model in a single stroke from a key/value array. A `load` method like that would make populating the object with any info you wanted pretty simple. Further, it could be extended by child classes with validation, etc. if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you must have the system-under-test (your framework) be able to use `new` to instantiate model objects directly, and each test needs to set the default values for its properties differently.

If this is the case, you can create a simple base class to populate a predefined set of properties upon construction. The solution below uses [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) from PHP 5.3, but you could easily achieve the same results without it with a slight tweak.

```
class MockModel
{
    public static $properties;

    public function __construct() {
        if (isset(static::$properties) && is_array(static::$properties)) {
            foreach (static::$properties as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class MockBook extends MockModel { /* nothing needed */ }

function testBookWithTitle() {
    MockBook::$properties = array(
        'title' => 'To Kill a Mockingbird'
    );
    $book = new MockBook;
    self::assertEquals('To Kill a Mockingbird', $book->title);
}
```

As long as you can provide the class name to use with `new` to your framework, this should work. If you need to be able to create more than one instance of the same mock class in during a single call to your framework, you'll need to enhance the above with some sort of indexing mechanism.

Comment: It's for model testing. I want to create a faux Author and Books model and test their relationship. When I use `$author->books` the framework needs to instantiate a new `Book` object and read its properties to seed it with data and determine the relationship criteria to/from `Author`. So no, I can't really inject my mocked `Book` object anywhere since it's the frameworks job to instantiate these objects dynamically. I just need to throw a `Author` class into memory with those properties without concertedly defining that class in the code.

Comment: Look at my last example in the question. I just need to be able to write those kinds of classes into memory without hard-coding it anywhere. I thought I could leverage the Mock Object Builder from PHPUnit but I'm not sure it has the functionality to do that.

Comment: @MikeB - See my update. Is this what you're seeking to achieve?